# Jekyll server does not start locally

Tags: css, ruby, visual-studio, jekyll

I am creating a GitHub Pages Jekyll website. When I start the Jekyll server locally to edit the theme, I get an error when compiling this SCSS file:

```scss
---
---

// start content

$green:   #08a057 !default;
$blue:    #3d61fd !default;

@import 'bootstrap/bootstrap';

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=PT+Sans:wght@400;700&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=PT+Serif:wght@400;700&display=swap');

/* add additional CSS rules below */
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
  }
  
body {
    background:#fff;
    font-size:17px;
    transition: all 200ms linear;
    font-family: "PT Sans",sans-serif;
    line-height:1.7;
    color: #333;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    padding-top:116px;
    
}
```

If I remove the first two lines, the server starts, but no longer applies the layout.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Please check the edit I have applied to your question  - which lines were removed, what's the error message?